# AngularJS $window.open on mobile device

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that and I'm using $window.open() to open a PDF in the browser. This works fine on a computer, but it doesn't work on a mobile device.
Using Chrome, I opened my app in "mobile mode" and I get the javascript error "$window is not defined". How can I get this to work on a mobile device?

Comment: try with `window.open()`

Comment: How are you injecting `$window`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by murli2308, window.open() is the solution.